# Tree to Array in Javascript - 2x difference in performance between spread (...) and generator based syntax

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

What causes the difference in performance between these two implementations of pre-order traversal?

So I wanted to practice some functional programming in JavaScript and to create some functions that can operate on trees. I checked a bunch of articles abut it, and it seems that functional programming is not the way to go in JavaScript and that for loops and other imperative functionalities are quite common. I wanted to test which way of traversing a tree would be faster - the functional one based on spread syntax or the one based on `yield`. It seems that the spread syntax based is much faster - it's roughly twice as fast as the one based on `yield`! Also, it has quite a lot of variance, while the

I got this code from being as slow as 700op/s and as fast as 1500 op/s while the `yield` based implementation is stable around 400 op/s.

Here is the code:

```js
class BinaryTreeNode {
  constructor(key, value = key, parent = null) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }

  get isLeaf() {
    return this.left === null && this.right === null;
  }

  get hasChildren() {
    return !this.isLeaf;
  }
}

class BinaryTree {
  constructor(key, value = key) {
    this.root = new BinaryTreeNode(key, value);
  }

  seql(node = this.root) {
    return [
      node,
      ...(node.left ? this.seql(node.left) : []),
      ...(node.right ? this.seql(node.right) : []),
    ];
  }

  *preOrderTraversal(node = this.root) {
    yield node;
    if (node.left) yield* this.preOrderTraversal(node.left);
    if (node.right) yield* this.preOrderTraversal(node.right);
  }

  fill() {
    for (let node of this.seql()) {
      if (node.left === null) {
        node.left = new BinaryTreeNode(Math.random(), Math.random(), node);
      }
      if (node.right === null) {
        node.right = new BinaryTreeNode(Math.random(), Math.random(), node);
      }
    }
  }
}

let i = 1;
const tree = new BinaryTree(Math.random, Math.random());
while (i < 13) {
  tree.fill();
  i++;
}

const test = () => {
  [...tree.preOrderTraversal()];
  //[...tree.seql()];
};

const iterationsC = 50;
const main = async () => {
  const runBaseline = (iterations = iterationsC) => {
    let startTime = new Date().getTime();
    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      // no operation
    }
    let endTime = new Date().getTime();
    return endTime - startTime;
  };

  const runTest = (iterations = iterationsC) => {
    let startTime = new Date().getTime();

    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) test();

    let endTime = new Date().getTime();
    let baselineTime = runBaseline(iterations);
    let totalTime = endTime - startTime - baselineTime;
    let fnTime = (totalTime / iterations).toFixed(10);
    let operations = Math.floor((1000 / totalTime) * iterations);

    console.log(`total: ${totalTime}, time: ${fnTime}, op/sec: ${operations}`);
  };

  while (true) {
    runTest();
    await sleep(50);
  }

  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
};

main();
```

The code for the binary tree comes from [30 seconds blog](https://github.com/30-seconds/30-seconds-blog) and is licensed under CC 4.0 and the code from benchmarking comes from [this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/benchmarking-javascript-e57d34b5dcc3) blogpost.

This is a massive difference. What can be the cause of that?